# INSERT stored procedure does not return the recordset with ADO

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure-sql-database, sql-insert, ado

I have an `INSERT` stored procedure that works just fine when executing inside SQL Server, but when I run the same stored procedure using ADO, it does not return the recordset as it is supposed to. I tried for the rows affected and the result is the same.

My main goal is to make sure the stored procedure runs without an error so I can take decisions in my application based on that. What is the best approach to fix this?

This is pretty much how I have written the stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE MyProc
AS
    DECLARE @sql AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
BEGIN
    SELECT @sql = 'INSERT INTO tableB (col1, col2) 
                       SELECT c1, c2 
                       FROM TableA 
                       LEFT JOIN tableB ON tableA.Id = tableB.Id;'
END

BEGIN
    EXECUTE(@sql)        
    SELECT @@ERROR AS ErrorNumber
    RETURN 
END
```

and on the ADO/VBA side I have:

```
DIM rs AS ADODB.Recordset

rs.Open "exec MyProc", MyActiveConnection
```

Comment: `@slq` and `@sql` are two different variables. is this a typing error? And why do you need a dynamic statement at all?

Comment: An insert doesn't return a record set, you wouldn't get rows when you execute it in SSMS. Why the dynamic sql though?

Comment: @Zhorov it was a typo, fixed now

Comment: As per other comments; 1. Dynamic SQL is not required and just complicates it. 2. This does not return a recordset. Do you mean a rowcount?

Comment: @HoneyBadger I run it in VSCode and I get the error number, it is essentially a number not rows

Comment: I am running this from inside Excel VBA practically. So I send parameters such as table name etc, but for the sake of keeping the post lean I simplified the SPI, but I kept the dynamic SQL format just to make sure I am asking the question right

Comment: 1. Why are you using dynamic-sql in your stored procedure. 99.9% of the time : CEASE AND DESIST this practice.  CEASE AND DESIST.  Please...stop writing dynamic sql when you do not need it. 2. You need some kind of SELECT statement in the procedure (your current SELECT is for the INSERT..it does not "return something to the caller". . 3. (after you do some kind of SELECT statement (not associated with the insert).......you'll need to do something with your "rs". if (! rs.eof) then << you check if you have anything then start looping on it .. or something.

Comment: Do you get the expected result when you place `SET NOCOUNT ON` as first line in the procedure? This stops the SQL Server to return the count of the affected rows as a resultset.

Comment: yes, I have `SET NOCOUNT ON` in place; without it ADO gets confused regardless of the type of statements unless if we want to return the rows affected

Comment: @granadaCoder `rs` is not returned even if the SP is run successfully so the `object=nothing` and cannot be analyzed more. I have included a `SELECT` statement that returns the right result, but not through ADO, so at this point I am not sure this is a SQL Server shortcoming or ADO problem. Check this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/stored-procedures/return-data-from-a-stored-procedure?view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: *"yes, I have SET NOCOUNT ON in place;"* `NOCOUNT` isn't set in the above procedure at all though, so where are you setting this?

Comment: @Larnu I added to the question, for keeping the question short I did not write the whole thing, it is in fact way bigger than this, but since I am sure it is not the problem I did not include it.

Comment: Sounds like you giving us a representative version of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE MyProc
 (@ErrorCode   AS int OUTPUT,        
 @ErrorDesc   AS nvarchar(1000) OUTPUT )

AS
    DECLARE @sql AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
BEGIN

 BEGIN TRY    

    SELECT @sql = 'INSERT INTO tableB (col1, col2) 
                       SELECT c1, c2 
                       FROM TableA 
                       LEFT JOIN tableB ON tableA.Id = tableB.Id;'
EXECUTE(@sql)
END TRY        
        
 BEGIN CATCH        
  BEGIN         
   IF @@ERROR <> 0         
   BEGIN        
    SET @ErrorCode = (SELECT ERROR_NUMBER())        
    SET @ErrorDesc = (SELECT ERROR_MESSAGE())        
   END        
  END        
          
 END CATCH        
         
END
```

As of me if error occur its give you errorcode and errordescription use output parameter

```
DIM rs AS ADODB.Recordset

rs.Open "exec MyProc 0,''", MyActiveConnection
```

[Please check sql output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PwP8b.png)

Comment: when I ran this in VSCode, it returned NULL even though there was an error

Comment: Dim ErrorCode As Integer = 0
 Dim ErrorDesc As String = ""
rs.Open "exec MyProc ErrorCode,ErrorDesc", MyActiveConnection


  If ErrorCode <> 0 Then
                Throw New System.Data.DataException( _
                ErrorDesc)
            End If